# Joystick Code error of undeclared variables

Tags: c, linux, compiler-errors, joystick

I am attempting to write a code to read a joystick axis values, which i eventually hope to be able to use the values for controlling motors. After copious amounts of trying to figure out C and how on earth to use the joystick api I wrote this code. to start with it came only with one variable undeclared error then as I *improved* code, making it more readable and easier to understand I got another one of the same when I went to compile it hoping the first would have gone away! 
This is my code (excuse the commenting):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <linux/joystick.h> /* lots of included headers because */ 
                            /*  I wasn't sure which I needed!   */

#define JS_EVENT_AXIS           0x02    /* joystick moved */

int open_joystick() {

    int fd;                             /* fd declared I thought */
        fd = open ("/dev/js0", O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);

    return fd;                          /* code likes something to return */
}

int read_joystick_thrust_axis(struct js_event js) /* declare r_j_t_a variable and the js instance */


    while (1) {                                          /* loop forever */
        while (read (fd, &js, sizeof(js)) > 0) {         /* while there is an event */
          if (js_event.type == JS_EVENT_AXIS) {          /* and if that is an axis event */
            if (js_event.number == 1) {                  /* and if that event is on the right axis */  
               printf ("Joystick at %8hb\n", js.value);  /* print that instance of the joysticks value */
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
    return 0; }            /* keeping C happy by returning something */
```

And the errors i get back from gcc are:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/rc $ gcc joystick.c
joystick.c: In function ‘read_joystick_thrust_axis’:
joystick.c:24:16: error: ‘fd’ undeclared (first use in this function)
joystick.c:24:16: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
joystick.c:25:8: error: ‘js_event’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Could someone please explain why I am getting these errors and suggest a fix?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `fd` is declared in `open_joystick` and its lexical scope is the scope of `open_joystick`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`open_joystick` sets `fd`, but `fd` is local to `open_joystick`, and therefore not readable by  `read_joystick_thrust_axis`. Convert `read_joystick_thrust_axis` to allow `fd` to be passed as an argument, and pass the return value of `open_joystick`, like this:

Change:

```
int read_joystick_thrust_axis(struct js_event js)
```

to

```
int read_joystick_thrust_axis(int fd, struct js_event js)
```

Then when you call it (from `main` or whatever), do

```
int fd;
fd = open_joystick();
...
int read_joystick_thrust_access (fd, whatever);
```

Re the `js_event` error, the variable is named `js`, and is of type `struct js_event`. Therefore you want to refer to `js.type` not `js_event.type`.

Comment: Thank you so much makes far more sense now! How would I convert 'read_joystick_thrust _axis' to allow 'fd' to be passed as an argument? And i am not sure I understand what/where you were talking about with you bit about "pass the return value of 'open_joystick' " could you try re explaining? Sorry a bit of a newbie here.

Comment: I've amended the answer.

Comment: Thanks, okay I think I understand now! So the bit about calling it from main I would only use if I wanted to call it from another function? Sorry

Comment: You must be calling it from another function, or it wouldn't be called.